# What does "para public use16" mean when declaring a segment in TASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

I know that this code here is supposed to create a segment containing the 16-bit code and the data.

```
segment code16 para public use16
assume cs:code16, ds:code16
```

But I'm not sure what is the format here.

I think that `segment` means we are declaring a segment, `code16` is the name, but I'm not sure about `para public use16`.

And may be `assume cs:code16, ds:code16` means that we'll be using it for both the code and data.

Comment: Your `assume` tells TASM that `cs` and `ds` are assumed to point to the `code16` segment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`para`
This is the [segment alignment](http://www.plantation-productions.com/Webster/www.artofasm.com/DOS/ch08/CH08-2.html#HEADING2-74). `para` is short for "paragraph", which in this context means 16 bytes. So you're aligning the segment on a 16 byte boundary.

`public`
This is the [segment combine type](http://www.plantation-productions.com/Webster/www.artofasm.com/DOS/ch08/CH08-2.html#HEADING2-164). `public` means that all segments with this name should be concatenated into a single segment.

`use16`
This means that the segment will use 16-bit encoding for instruction by default, and that 32-bit instructions will need prefixed opcodes if they'd otherwise be ambigous.

Comment: I thought that 16-bit or 32-bit instruction set was a global setting for the CPU, i.e. real mode vs protected mode. Does this mean that each segment can have a different instruction set?

Comment: @sashoalm: Many instructions have identical encodings for 16-bit and 32-bit operands (for example `PUSH AX` and `PUSH EAX`). A prefix (`0x66`) is used to separate between the two. The `useNN` setting controls which of the two that will get prefixed, i.e. how the _assembler_ should encode the instructions (e.g. with `use16` the 16-bit encoding would be the default, while the 32-bit variant would be prefixed). How the _CPU_ inteprets the code when it runs is a different matter, but you should of course make sure that you assemble for the same mode that you intend to run your code in.